# Change a value of a variable in an angular component from an event listener handler

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an event listener and an event handler:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    document.addEventListener('focusin', this.lastElementFocused);
}
```

and the handler function:

```
lastElementFocused() {
    this.lastActiveElement = document.activeElement;
}
```

lastActiveElement is created in my component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  lastActiveElement: Element;
  ...
```

However, the handler function isn't able to change the value of the variable, when I try to use the variable outside the handler function it doesn't contain the updated value.

Can anyone help?